# Automated Process to cut and paste excel data from columns to rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create VBA code to cut and paste data from BCol1,BCol2,BCol3 into row directly beneath that record under ACol1,ACol2,ACol3. Likewise for CCol1,CCol2,CCol3 and so on. Also I want common column data to be copied in first column for that specific record.

I would like to create a code that loops for an entire set of data as I've 100+ columns, 10000+ rows and 50000+ Excel files to process data. I need an automated solution.

I can't open each Excel file and implement VBA code, so any pointer for that is also appreciated.

This is how my sample data looks

[image: This is how my sample data looks]

This is how my sample data should look like

[image: This is how my sample data should look like]

[Edit:]
I've tried the following code:

```
Sub cut_paste()
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
    Rows(i + 1).Insert
Next i

For j = 2 To 4 * (lastRow - 1) + 1 Step 4
    Range("E" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B" & j + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C" & j + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("G" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D" & j + 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("H" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B" & j + 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C" & j + 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D" & j + 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("K" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("B" & j + 3).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("L" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("C" & j + 3).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("M" & j).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D" & j + 3).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next j

For k = 2 To 4 * (lastRow - 1) + 1 Step 4
    Range("A" & k).Select
    Selection.Copy
    For l = k + 1 To k + 3 Step 1
        Range("A" & l).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next l
Next k
End Sub
```

I'm able to do this for sample data but for actual data its hectic task to do this way.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Show what you tried to do. It looks like you want us to write the solution now.

Comment: I have no experience in VBA, just looking for something to start with.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=excel+vba  Good starting point

Comment: Thanks @newguy :P Will also go through youtube after solving this. I kind of started liking VBA and will definitely learn it. But, right now I think Google is my only friend.

Comment: I used to just record a macro doing what I wanted to do manually, and then just modify the code to make it more generic..  I was then able to figure out how to do stuff that way.  The recorded macro is usually a little verbose and sets properties that aren't necessary, so just cut those bits out.

Answer (score 0):

here is a vba procedure that you can adapt to your needs

```
Sub aargh()
    sourcePath = "c:\sourcepath\"
    destpath = "c:\destpath\"
    f = Dir(sourcePath & "\*.xls*")
    While f <> "" 'loop tru all xls files in source directory
        Workbooks.Open (sourcePath & f) 
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        lastcolumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ' copy range to array a
        a = Range(Range("A1"), Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn))
        Cells.ClearContents
        For i = LBound(a, 1) + 1 To UBound(a, 1)
            For j = LBound(a, 2) + 1 To UBound(a, 2) Step 3
                li = li + 1
                Cells(li, 1) = a(i, LBound(a, 2))
                For k = 1 To 3
                    Cells(li, k + 1) = a(i, LBound(a, 2) + k + j - 2)
                Next k
            Next j
        Next i
        ' save modified file as new file
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs destpath & f
        f = Dir()
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it a bit variable, you can use something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub dada()
  Dim left_part As Long, split_part As Long, num_parts As Long, x, y

  x = Selection.Value2
  left_part = 1
  split_part = 3

  num_parts = (UBound(x, 2) - left_part) / split_part
  ReDim y(1 To num_parts * UBound(x), 1 To left_part + split_part)

  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long

  For i = 1 To UBound(x)
    For j = 1 To num_parts

      l = l + 1

      For k = 1 To left_part
        y(l, k) = x(i, k)
      Next

      For k = 1 To split_part
        y(l, k + left_part) = x(i, k + (j - 1) * split_part + left_part)
      Next

    Next
  Next

  Sheets.Add.Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(y), UBound(y, 2)) = y

End Sub
```

Just set `left_part` to the count of columns which will not be split. (in your example this is just common1, common2....) so if there are multiple columns then change that.
Also set `split_part` to the size of the parts to split. (in your example this is 3 for *Col1, *Col2 and *Col3) ao if that differs, just change that to your needs.

Now select your range to split without the upper headers (will be A2:M4 in your example) and run the macro.

You also can set x to `x = [A2:M4].Value2` or whatever you need if you do not want to select the range.

After splitting everything up, it will be pasted in a new sheet without formatting. But having everything below each other should make it easy to to copy the formats to the columns as you need them (or after copying the date wherever you want it).

Just keep in mind to also copy the headers later on (as they seem to change in an unknown way, I've excluded them here)

If anything does not work as you want it or if you just have any questions, just ask ;)

hint: every interaction with the sheet will be MUCH slower then doing this just with variables. This way (for mid-ranged tables), executing this code and formatting it manually afterwards will be faster then copy/pasting via macro)